# translate3d makes element jump

Tags: css, velocity.js, translate3d

I use transform's translate3d to center the popup div in a container.

```
//CSS
element
{
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

//JS
    $btn.click(function(){
         $popupContainer1.velocity({ opacity: 1}, { display: "block"});
    });
```

In desktop browsers, it works fine but in mobile browser, it jumps. When user clicks on a button the popup div gets **opacity value** 1 and **display** property to **block** from JavaScript. It gets displayed below and to the left of the supposed position then get moved to actual position.

I tried applying the following snippet for improvement as suggested in many posts here in Stackoverflow but no success.

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Clicking on close button on popup container is handled with the following function.

```
$rdCloseBtn.click(function(){
        $rdPopupElements.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, {
            display : 'none',
            mobileHA: false
        });
        setDefault();
    });
```

I reset the animation with below code.

```
function setDefault(id){
        if (id === 0) {
            $rdPopupElement0.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdPopupElement_0_Text.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdPopupElement0Clock.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdJumpingArrow.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdClockingArrow0.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdClockingFiller0.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdClockingArrow1.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
        }
        else if (id === 1) {
            $rdPopupElement1.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdRS0.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $imgClipBoardClock.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdRS1.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdTick0.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdTick1.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);

            $rdPopupElement_1_Text.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdClipboardClock.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
        }
        else if (id === 2) {
            $rdPopupElement2.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdMaginifier.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdRedDot.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdMagFiller.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdArrowFlow.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
            $rdPopupElement_2_Text.velocity({ opacity : 0 }, 0);
        }

        else {
            setDefault(0);
            setDefault(1);
            setDefault(2);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am guessing it is due to the translate, try it with position absolute and see if it jumps. If it doesn't you will know why

Comment: You might wanna try `translate(-50%, -50%)` instead of translate3d and just make sure that that's not the issue.

Comment: Which mobile browser are you seeing the issue in?

Comment: Safari, Chrome and Firefox in mobile.

Comment: @Ravan I have tried with translate; it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's using Velocity v1 - which isn't the best thing where `transform` is concerned, as on mobile devices it attempts to mess around with the `transform` property itself, and I've got a feeling that's happening here. At the least try adding the option `mobileHA: false` to it and see if that helps.

Failing that, maybe have a look at trying with the Velocity v2 beta (check the github page for details), `display` becomes a property instead of an option, but there's (currently) no mobile hardware acceleration on it (mobile devices and browsers have improved since then) - and it'll leave your properties alone - it is still in beta while I'm ironing out some bugs and ensuring it is good enough quality though!

Comment: mobileHA: false works but it introduces new issues. I have complete function on popup animation. If I close the popup window before the animation complete then open the popup again I see elements are visible already.

Comment: In v1 mobileHA can completely destroy any transform values you have on the element to begin with - which is why there's the jump. You also can't use the `transform` property in V1, you need to use the various `translateX` and `translateY` properties in combination instead - but if you add them and use forcefeeding for them (values of `["50%", "50%"]` then it'd duplicate the css and should work even on mobile.